# How DELETE operations impact data table size in Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL Pool?

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm facing an abnormal growth in the data size for tables inside a Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL Pool.

In particular I noticed that even if I delete some rows from a table, the table data size doesn't decrease.

In order to monitor the table size I'm using the view (vTableSizes) recommended in the MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql- data-warehouse-tables-overview#table-size-queries.

The table size is exponentially growing because the data ingestion process delete and re-insert modified data (standard approach for data warehouse fact tables).

Why table data size is not reduced when a DELETE operation is performed?

Answer (score 0):

REBUILD table should help here. It helps to rebuild take and claim free space. Kindly try and see.

> ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable WITH REBUILD;